# Dynamic WPF generation with Linq to XML

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, linq, dynamic

I have been trying to create some dynamic Xaml.

I have the following c#

```
private void LoadUI()
{
    XNamespace xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation";

    dynamic UI = new XElement(xmlns + "Grid",
                              new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"),
                              new XAttribute("Name", "Grid1"),
                              new XElement(xmlns + "Grid.ColumnDefinitions",
                                           new XElement(xmlns + "ColumnDefinition", new XAttribute("Width", "100*")),
                                           new XElement(xmlns + "ColumnDefinition", new XAttribute("Width", "200*"))),
                              new XElement(xmlns + "StackPanel", new XAttribute("Name", "StackLabels"),
                                           new XAttribute("Margin", "3"),
                                           from column in this.TableSchema
                                           where column.IsPrimaryKey == 0 && column.DataType != "timestamp"
                                           select
                                               new XElement(xmlns + "Label", new XAttribute("Height", "28"),
                                                            new XAttribute("Name", column.ColumnName + "Label"),
                                                            new XAttribute("HorizontalContentAlignment", "Right"),
                                                            column.ColumnName)),
                              new XElement(xmlns + "StackPanel",
                                           new XAttribute("Grid.Column", "1"),
                                           new XAttribute("Name", "StackFields"),
                                           new XAttribute("Margin", "3")
                                  ,

                from column in this.TableSchema
                where column.IsPrimaryKey == 0 && column.DataType != "timestamp"
                select
                GetUIElement(column)));

    this.DynamicContent.Content = XamlReader.Load(UI.CreateReader());

}
```

The error i get is in trying to create the Grid.Column. The exact error is 
{"Der unbekannte Member \"Grid.Column\" kann nicht festgelegt werden."}

so it doesn't know the Grid.Column...

Anyone any ideas?

It works fine with the new XAttribute("Grid.Column", "1"), line commented out just doesn't show what I want naturally!

The generated Grid looks like the following:

```
 <Grid xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="Grid1"   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="200*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <StackPanel Name="StackLabels" Margin="3">
    <Label Height="28" Name="NummerLabel" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Nummer</Label>    
  </StackPanel>
  <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Name="StackFields" Margin="3">
    <TextBox Height="28" Name="txtNummer" Text="{Binding Path=Nummer}" />
    </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: And is the error happening in the XamlReader.Load or earlier? Better post the full error.

Comment: Sorry Yes, the error is happenng in the XamlReader.Load. The Xaml in the UI looks good to me...

Comment: Try to load the generated xaml in VS and let it auto-format. It's easy to miss a close tag or something. Can post it (a sample) here?

Comment: What happens when you use `XamlReader.Parse(xaml)` instead?

Comment: Try to replace 
  

    dynamic UI = ...

with

    var UI = ...

I have mocked your sample and got it to work with this change. Are you sure you really need a "dynamic" type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

It is reproducible. It seems there is some problem in the interaction of XamlReader.Load with the provided XmlReader. It throws XamlParseException *"Cannot set unknown member 'Grid.Column'."*

Converting to string and loading XAML from it works, oddly:

```
var xml = UI.ToString();
var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml));
var content = XamlReader.Load(reader); // works now.
```

I see you're creating XML markup only to convert it to UI objects. Why not simply create UI objects from the queries?

Comment: The xaml is valid as soon as I ignore the grid.column. It would be possible I just liked this method...

Comment: I can reproduce your problem. I've edited my answer with the exception in English, if you'd like to search for it.